# Iterate through json on webpage ( jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a form I collect data from and then I insert them in url string,
thus I get url like http://terminal2.expedia.com/x/mhotels/search?city=hersbruck&checkInDate=2016-12-01&checkOutDate=2016-12-03&room1=2&apikey=RZjKNligNc0QZJvV9HP1nbFm1jrghgLK
This url returns valid json directly on the page

```
{
  numberOfRoomsRequested: 1,
  filterUnavailableHotelsRequested: false,
  totalHotelCount: 94,
  availableHotelCount: 60,
  searchRegionId: "6124915",
  searchRegionCity: "Hersbruck",
  deepLinkUrl: "https://www.expedia.com/Hersbruck-Hotels.d6124915.Travel-Guide-Hotels",
     hotelList: [
       {
     sortIndex: "0",
     hotelId: "2813073",
     name: "Md Hotel Restaurant Bauer",
     localizedName: "Md Hotel Restaurant Bauer",
     nonLocalizedName: "Md Hotel Restaurant Bauer",
     address: "Martin Luther Str 16",
     city: "Hersbruck",
     ........
```

and I try to get some data from it to create table, with such code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#submit-btn').click(function(s) {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        var place = (document.querySelectorAll('#place')[0].value);
        var check_in = (document.querySelectorAll('#check-in')[0].value);
        var check_out = (document.querySelectorAll('#check-out')[0].value);
        var api_key = "RZjKNligNc0QZJvV9HP1nbFm1jrghgLK";
        var url = "http://terminal2.expedia.com/x/mhotels/search?city=" + place + "&checkInDate=" + check_in + "&checkOutDate=" + check_out + "&room1=2&apikey=" + api_key + ""

       $.getJSON(url, function (data){
          var div = $("#result");
          var table = '<table><tbody>';
            for (i in data) {
                var tr = '<tr><td>'+data[i].name+'</td><td>'+data[i].city+'</td></tr>'
                table = table+tr;
           }
            table = table + "</tbody></table>";
            div.html(table);
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

but I receive table with `undefined`
What I do wrong, please point me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to display the hotels from the hotelList returned by the API. Then wouldn't your loop be more like:

```
for (hotel in data.hotelList) {
  var tr = '<tr><td>'+ hotel.name+'</td><td>'+ hotel.city+'</td></tr>'
  table = table+tr;
}
```

I changed i for hotel for clarity sake.

But since I can't see the whole JSON, I don't know if my guess is right.

Comment: This is the right idea, but `hotel` is the index, not the value. You shouldn't loop through arrays with for..in anyway.

Comment: You can click url in above  and see the whole json

Comment: @Gabrielle Bastien thanks for idea. It works if  I do  `var tr = '<tr><td>'+data.hotelList[i].name+'</td><td>'+data.hotelList[i].city+'</td></tr>'`     Update you answer for me to vote if you want.